# Animating Data By Year Only in Carto?

Tags: carto, time, animation

I'm trying to animate the opening and closing of particular businesses using yearly travel guides.  I've created a data base that contains all the addresses and all of the years they appear so for instance:

```
1965 Copper Lantern
1966 Copper Lantern
1967 Copper Lantern
etc.
```

When visualizing the data using Carto DB the animation is spotty and it seems that it is looking for information for every single month of each year.  How can I change this so that it only animates the entire year rather than each month in the year?

I am completely new to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to change the steps in torque animation.

If you are using the wizard just set steps to the same number of years you have.

If you use cartocss use:

> -torque-frame-count: NUMBER_OF_YEARS;,

Comment: This doesn't work.  I have 9 years thus far and when I enter 9 in the frame count the animation is blank and at year 8 they all show up and disappear at year nine.  My dates are in a column that is a "number" data type, not "date" data type...could this be causing the problem?